# Drupal handle and process POST request webhook from activecampaign

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm trying to make a small Drupal project with ActiveCampaign.

I already implemented the activecampaign webform and it works but what I want to do is use the webhooks that activecampaingn can offer for me using POST hits to my website url to create new users using their email address and first + lastname.
In the automation tools of activecampaign I can specify at wich URL the POST webhook is sent and I have an array of variables wich contains data about the subscriber.

What I need is a way to catch this POST hits sent by activecampaign in my Drupal and then I can manage to extract the variables sent and make the user accounts.

Wich way would you recommend for this? 
Can module Drupal Services do this?